# Adding a simple left/right swipe gesture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swipe

**I need to add a simple left/right swipe gesture** so that the 'selected' image cycles when swiped on mobile, similar to clicking the buttons in the hero component, also similar to pressing the left/right arrow keys on a keyboard

I don't have the most experience with JavaScript so if anyone could tell me what exactly to write and where so that I can completely wrap up this project.

Here is a demo: http://nufaith.ca/justinatkins/

**Code:**

```
Vue.component('hero-bg', {
  template: `
    <div class="hero-bg">
      <div class="hero">
        <img id="pushed" :src="selected"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    `,
  props: ['selected']
});

Vue.component('hero-bg-empty', {
  template: `
    <div class="hero-bg">
      <div class="hero">
      <span style="display:block;height:100px;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
});

Vue.component('hero', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <topbar v-if="!gridEnabled"></topbar>
      <topbar2 v-if="gridEnabled"></topbar2>
      <hero-bg :selected="selectedItem.img" v-if="!gridEnabled"></hero-bg>
      <hero-bg-empty v-if="gridEnabled"></hero-bg-empty>
      <div class="hero-container" v-if="!gridEnabled">
        <div class="hero">
          <img :src="selectedItem.img" v-if="thing" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-desc">
          <button class="control left" @click="previous">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-left"></i>
          </button>
          <span class="hero-desc-title" v-html="title"></span>
          <button class="control right" @click="next">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"></i>
          </button>
          <br/>
          <button class="view-all-button" @click="enableGrid">OVERVIEW</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `,
  data() {
    return {
      gridEnabled: false,
      selected: 0,
      thing: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItem() {
      return info[this.selected];
    },
    title() {
      const comma = this.selectedItem.title.indexOf(',');
      const len = this.selectedItem.title.length;
      const strBeginning = this.selectedItem.title.substring(comma, 0);
      const strEnd = this.selectedItem.title.substring(comma, len);
      if (this.selectedItem.title.includes(',')) {
        return `<span>${strBeginning}<span class="font-regular font-muted">${strEnd}</span></span>`;
      }
      return this.selectedItem.title;
    },
    maxImages() {
      return info.length - 1;
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        this.previous();
        return;
      }

      if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        this.next();
        return;
      }
    });
    Event.$on('updateImg', index => {
      this.selected = index;
      this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.selected === this.maxImages ? (this.selected = 0) : (this.selected += 1);
    },
    previous() {
      this.selected === 0 ? (this.selected = this.maxImages) : (this.selected -= 1);
    },
    enableGrid() {
      this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled;
      window.scroll(0, 0);
      Event.$emit('enableGrid');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: To anyone reading this question and answer now - I highly recommend following the solution by @treatycity below using HammerJS - I managed the implementation of it using only a few lines of code and still using my own custom functions for changing the slide on a slider I built!

Answer (score 28):

This is how I implemented **a simple swipe gesture** in one of my projects. You may check this out.

**Code:**

```
touchableElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    touchstartX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    touchstartY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
}, false);

touchableElement.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
    touchendX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    touchendY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
    handleGesture();
}, false);


function handleGesture() {
    if (touchendX < touchstartX) {
        console.log('Swiped Left');
    }

    if (touchendX > touchstartX) {
        console.log('Swiped Right');
    }

    if (touchendY < touchstartY) {
        console.log('Swiped Up');
    }

    if (touchendY > touchstartY) {
        console.log('Swiped Down');
    }

    if (touchendY === touchstartY) {
        console.log('Tap');
    }
}
```

Basically, `touchableElement` mentioned here, refers to the `DOM Element` that will receive the touch event. If you want to activate swipe options on your entire screen, then you may use your `body` tag as the touchable element. Or you may configure any specific `div` element as the touchable element, in case you just want the swipe gesture on that specific `div`.

On that `touchableElement`, we are adding 2 event-listeners here:

1. `touchstart`:
   this is when user **starts swiping**. We take that initial coordinates (x,y) and
   store them into touchstartX, touchstartY respectively.
2. `touchend`: this is when user **stops swiping**. We take that final coordinates (x, y) and store them into touchendX, touchendY respectively.

Keep in mind that, the origin of these coordinates is the top left corner of the screen. **x-coordinate increases** as you go from **left to right** and **y-coordinate increases** as you go from **top to bottom**.

Then, in `handleGesture()`, we just compare those 2 pair of coordinates (touchstartX, touchstartY) and (touchendX, touchendY), to detect different types of swipe gesture (up, down, left, right):

- `touchendX < touchstartX`: says that, user **started** swiping at a **higher X value** & **stopped** swiping at a **lower X value**. That means, swiped **from right to left** (Swiped Left).
- `touchendX > touchstartX`: says that, user **started** swiping at a **lower X value** & **stopped** swiping at a **higher X value**. That means, swiped **from left to right** (Swiped Right).
- `touchendY < touchstartY`: says that, user **started** swiping at a **higher Y value** & **stopped** swiping at a **lower Y value**. That means, swiped **from bottom to top** (Swiped Up).
- `touchendY > touchstartY`: says that, user **started** swiping at a **lower Y value** & **stopped** swiping at a **higher Y value**. That means, swiped **from top to bottom** (Swiped Down).

You may add the code for these 4 different events (Swipe Up/Down/Left/Right), on the corresponding `if` blocks, as shown on the code.

Comment: could you elaborate in such a way that shows me how to apply this to my code? i'm not 100% versed in javascript so i keep making mistakes that break my code when i try

Comment: please let me know!

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: an optional suggestion is to add `if (Math.abs(touchendX - touchstartX) > 50)`  at the start of `handleGesture()` function to get a better user-understanding exprience

Answer (score 9):

I took smmehrab’s answer, added some thresholds to avoid accidental swipes, and turned it into a little library. Might come in handy, so here it is:

```js
export default class TouchEvent {
    static SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50; // Minimum difference in pixels at which a swipe gesture is detected

    static SWIPE_LEFT   = 1;
    static SWIPE_RIGHT  = 2;
    static SWIPE_UP     = 3;
    static SWIPE_DOWN   = 4;

    constructor(startEvent, endEvent) {
        this.startEvent = startEvent;
        this.endEvent = endEvent || null;
    }

    isSwipeLeft() {
        return this.getSwipeDirection() == TouchEvent.SWIPE_LEFT;
    }

    isSwipeRight() {
        return this.getSwipeDirection() == TouchEvent.SWIPE_RIGHT;
    }

    isSwipeUp() {
        return this.getSwipeDirection() == TouchEvent.SWIPE_UP;
    }

    isSwipeDown() {
        return this.getSwipeDirection() == TouchEvent.SWIPE_DOWN;
    }

    getSwipeDirection() {
        if (!this.startEvent.changedTouches || !this.endEvent.changedTouches) {
            return null;
        }

        let start = this.startEvent.changedTouches[0];
        let end = this.endEvent.changedTouches[0];

        if (!start || !end) {
            return null;
        }

        let horizontalDifference = start.screenX - end.screenX;
        let verticalDifference = start.screenY - end.screenY;

        // Horizontal difference dominates
        if (Math.abs(horizontalDifference) > Math.abs(verticalDifference)) {
            if (horizontalDifference >= TouchEvent.SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                return TouchEvent.SWIPE_LEFT;
            } else if (horizontalDifference <= -TouchEvent.SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                return TouchEvent.SWIPE_RIGHT;
            }

        // Vertical or no difference dominates
        } else {
            if (verticalDifference >= TouchEvent.SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                return TouchEvent.SWIPE_UP;
            } else if (verticalDifference <= -TouchEvent.SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                return TouchEvent.SWIPE_DOWN;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    setEndEvent(endEvent) {
        this.endEvent = endEvent;
    }
}
```

### How to use

Simply feed it the events from `touchstart` and `touchend`:

```js
import TouchEvent from '@/TouchEvent'

let touchEvent = null;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    touchEvent = new TouchEvent(event);
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', handleSwipe);

function handleSwipe(event) {
    if (!touchEvent) {
         return;
    }

    touchEvent.setEndEvent(event);

    if (touchEvent.isSwipeRight()) {
        // Do something
    } else if (touchEvent.isSwipeLeft()) {
        // Do something different
    }

    // Reset event for next touch
    touchEvent = null;
}
```

Comment: can pass the element (in above example document) to the constructor and addEventListener there .. see my answer

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for [Hammer.JS](https://hammerjs.github.io/), unless you're trying to avoid dependencies. They have good documentation and examples for [getting started](https://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/)

My Vue knowledge is next to nothing, so I'm wary of this becoming a blind leading the blind scenario, but the first thing you'll have to do is add the dependency using either npm or yarn - then add it to the top of your file using

`import Hammer from 'hammerjs'`

Try adding the below code right above this line: `Event.$on('updateImg', index => {`

```js
const swipeableEl = document.getElementsByClassName('.hero')[0];
this.hammer = Hammer(swipeableEl)
this.hammer.on('swipeleft', () => this.next())
this.hammer.on('swiperight', () => this.previous())
```

If it doesn't work you'll have to check your developer tools / console log to see if it's logged any useful errors.

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/lisilinhart/pen/wxRQBo) might be a useful resource too:

Good luck.

Comment: any chance you could show me how to apply this directly in my code?

Comment: I'm not sure how much help I'll be, but have expanded the answer.

Comment: Thanks brother for help!

Comment: My favourite solution here by far! HammerJS is super easy to implement, I only had to add about 4 lines of codes and implemented the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` using functions I already had for my slider on a button click! Thanks for pointing this out @treatycity - I hadn't heard of it before!

Answer (score 1):

Using @smmehrab answer, I created a Vue 3 composable that also works for SSR builds.

```
import { onMounted, Ref } from 'vue'
export type SwipeCallback = (event: TouchEvent) => void;
export type SwipeOptions = {
    directinoal_threshold?: number; // Pixels offset to trigger swipe
};
export const useSwipe = (touchableElement: HTMLElement = null, options: Ref<SwipeOptions> = ref({
    directinoal_threshold: 10
})) => {
    const touchStartX = ref(0);
    const touchEndX = ref(0);
    const touchStartY = ref(0);
    const touchEndY = ref(0);

    onMounted(() => {
        if (!touchableElement)
            touchableElement = document.body;
        touchableElement.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
            touchStartX.value = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
            touchStartY.value = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
        }, false);

        touchableElement.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
            touchEndX.value = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
            touchEndY.value = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
            handleGesture(event);
        }, false);
    });

    const onSwipeLeft: Array<SwipeCallback> = [];
    const onSwipeRight: Array<SwipeCallback> = [];
    const onSwipeUp: Array<SwipeCallback> = [];
    const onSwipeDown: Array<SwipeCallback> = [];
    const onTap: Array<SwipeCallback> = [];

    const addEventListener = (arr: Array<SwipeCallback>, callback: SwipeCallback) => {
        arr.push(callback);
    };

    const handleGesture = (event: TouchEvent) => {
        if (touchEndX.value < touchStartX.value && (Math.max(touchStartY.value, touchEndY.value) - Math.min(touchStartY.value, touchEndY.value)) < options.value.directinoal_threshold) {
            onSwipeLeft.forEach(callback => callback(event));
        }

        if (touchEndX.value > touchStartX.value && (Math.max(touchStartY.value, touchEndY.value) - Math.min(touchStartY.value, touchEndY.value)) < options.value.directinoal_threshold) {
            onSwipeRight.forEach(callback => callback(event));
        }

        if (touchEndY.value < touchStartY.value && (Math.max(touchStartX.value, touchEndX.value) - Math.min(touchStartX.value, touchEndX.value)) < options.value.directinoal_threshold) {
            onSwipeUp.forEach(callback => callback(event));
        }

        if (touchEndY.value > touchStartY.value && (Math.max(touchStartX.value, touchEndX.value) - Math.min(touchStartX.value, touchEndX.value)) < options.value.directinoal_threshold) {
            onSwipeDown.forEach(callback => callback(event));
        }

        if (touchEndY.value === touchStartY.value) {
            onTap.forEach(callback => callback(event));
        }
    }
    return {
        onSwipeLeft: (callback: SwipeCallback) => addEventListener(onSwipeLeft, callback),
        onSwipeRight: (callback: SwipeCallback) => addEventListener(onSwipeRight, callback),
        onSwipeUp: (callback: SwipeCallback) => addEventListener(onSwipeUp, callback),
        onSwipeDown: (callback: SwipeCallback) => addEventListener(onSwipeDown, callback),
        onTap: (callback: SwipeCallback) => addEventListener(onTap, callback)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const { onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight } = useSwipe(document.body);
onSwipeLeft((e:TouchEvent) => {
    //logic
});
```

Comment: Too bad you made it typescript :(

Comment: @Craig shouldn't be much of a problem to remove the typings, not that much code.

Answer (score 0):

A reworking of [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617795/460084) answer:

```
function registerTouchEvent(element, callback) {
  const THRESHOLD = 50 // Minimum difference in pixels at which a swipe gesture is detected

  let startEvent
  element.addEventListener('touchstart', ev => startEvent = ev)

  element.addEventListener('touchend', endEvent => {
    if (!startEvent.changedTouches || !endEvent.changedTouches) return

    const start = startEvent.changedTouches[0]
    const end = endEvent.changedTouches[0]
    if (!start || !end) return

    const horizontalDifference = start.screenX - end.screenX
    const verticalDifference = start.screenY - end.screenY
    const horizontal = Math.abs(horizontalDifference) > Math.abs(verticalDifference) && Math.abs(verticalDifference) < THRESHOLD
    const vertical = !horizontal && Math.abs(horizontalDifference) < THRESHOLD

    let direction = 'diagonal';
    if (horizontal) direction = horizontalDifference >= THRESHOLD ? 'left' : (horizontalDifference <= -THRESHOLD ? 'right' : 'click')
    if (vertical) direction = verticalDifference >= THRESHOLD ? 'up' : (verticalDifference <= -THRESHOLD ? 'down' : 'click')

    callback(direction, startEvent, endEvent)
  })
}
```

To use:

```
registerTouchEvent(document, callback)
```

`callback` will receive a string left/right/up/down/click/diagonal and the startEvent and endEvent